# Fundamental group of sphere

Tags: homotopy-theory

To show that $S^3$ is not diffeomorphic to $S^2 \times S^1$, I'd like to say that their fundamental groups are not the same. 
So $\pi_1(S^3)= 0 $ but why is $\pi_1(S^2 \times S^1) = Z $ ?

Comment: $\pi_1$ takes products to products: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_group#Functoriality

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental group functor respects products in the sense that, for topological spaces $X, Y$,
$$\pi_1(X \times Y) \cong \pi_1(X) \times \pi_1(Y).$$

> So, if $Y = \mathbb{S}^1$, then $\pi_1 (X \times Y) \not\cong 0$.

Comment: But then we get $0 \times Z = Z $ ?

Comment: @Sasha Write it as $1 × ℤ = ℤ$. (I’m assuming you were confusing $0$ as the trivial group with the empty set $∅$ and thought $0 × ℤ = 0$.)

Comment: But I thought $\pi_1(S^2) = 0 $ ...

Comment: @Sasha $π_1(S^2) = \text{trivial group}$ and $\text{trivial group} × ℤ = ℤ$. You can write the trivial group as $0$ or $1$ (depending on whether you want to write your group operations multiplicatively or additively).

Comment: I see, I got confused with the meaning of $0$. Thanks !